# Creating a theme on WordPress : allow the admin panel to manage images

Tags: wordpress, image, themes, customization

*Sorry for bad english, it is not my first language*
I am new to WordPress, and I want to create my own theme from scratch.
I know functions like 
`wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main_menu'))`
or `the_content()` 
But I dont know what function to use in order to allow the WordPress "Customize Page" to choose what image to display on the page.
What do I need to write instead of `<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/myImage.png" />` so the website admin could change the image from the customize tool, without having to change or add an image manually in the wordPress directory ?
 Thank you for your time

Comment: You want output the Image that is set in the Post of a custompage? Try the_post_thumbnail ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/ )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your link is what I am looking for. Is there any detailled tutorial you could recommand me concerning WordPress theme development ?